# $scope.$apply() not updating template in dynamic directive

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, directive

I am adding a directive dynamically, on click of a button.
When I am trying to update dynamically generated directive template from its link function, it is not updating, but I am getting updated values in the console.
My code is:: 
MAIN directive::

```
app.directive("loadingDivStart",["$compile",function($compile){    
        return{
            restrict:"A",
            link:function ($scope, $elem, $attr){
                console.log('me');
                $elem.on('click',function(e){
                   newElement = $compile("<div id='loaderContainer' loading-directive  mywindow='windowProp' my-timer='timer' style='height:100%;'></div>")($scope);
                   $('body').append(newElement); 
                });
            }
        }    
    }])
```

Dynamic Directive

```
    app.directive("loadingDirective", ["$timeout","$interval", function ($timeout,$interval) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: {
                // mytimer: "=",
                windowProp: "=mywindow",
                myTimer: "="
            },
            template: "<div class='loader' style='width:{{windowProp.width}}px;height:{{windowProp.height}}px;'><div class='svgAnimation'>{{fromVal}}</div></div>",
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.fromVal = '08:00';
                $timeout(function(){
                    scope.fromVal = 'Hello';
                    console.log("Changed");
                }, 5000);
            }
        }

}]);
```

Value of **fromVal** is not updating after *$timeout*

Comment: How and  where you are calling ``loadingDivStart`` directive ??

Comment: I've reproduced the opposite;  the value of fromValue is not shown until AFTER the timeout elapses, and then 'Hello' is shown.  See plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ehofr1jeZbz5o7qQUTBi?p=preview.   Also, it's worth noting that this blend of jQuery and Angular is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Plnkr works flawless, but somehow my ionic code not working, it is not updating scope.fromVal in the template.

Comment: Just to adding in my question, I am using this code in ionic cordova.

Comment: You might want to look at this -- [Issue #12635 $timeout / $browser.defer broken on iOS 9 Cordova](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12635)

Comment: I am running this on Android Marshmallow